# build kde5 plasma-desktop fails

Tags: cmake, kde-plasma

I am building kde5 on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit but it always fails to configure plasma-desktop with Cmake. This is the error message:

```
 CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
X11_Xkbfile_LIB (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "kcm_keyboard" in directory /Projects/kde5/kdesrc/plasma-desktop/kcms/keyboard
    linked by target "kded_keyboard" in directory /Projects/kde5/kdesrc/plasma-desktop/kcms/keyboard
    linked by target "xkb_rules_test" in directory /Projects/kde5/kdesrc/plasma-desktop/kcms/keyboard/tests
    linked by target "iso_codes_test" in directory /Projects/kde5/kdesrc/plasma-desktop/kcms/keyboard/tests
    linked by target "geometry_parser_test" in directory /Projects/kde5/kdesrc/plasma-desktop/kcms/keyboard/tests
    linked by target "flags_test" in directory /Projects/kde5/kdesrc/plasma-desktop/kcms/keyboard/tests
    linked by target "keyboard_daemon_test" in directory /Projects/kde5/kdesrc/plasma-desktop/kcms/keyboard/tests
```

Everything else is compiled, this is the only one with problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that a cmake file cannot find a required library. The name `X11_Xkbfile_LIB` indicates that it should be one of the libraries that provide C bindings for X11 ("xkb"). Maybe installing [`libxcb-xkb-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/trusty/libxcb-xkb-dev) helps?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction, my system was missing a symlink of the library, the *so.1 to *.so

Answer (score 0):

SUCCESS: Hi, i ran into the exact same problem. i had no clue but here is the solution:

1. I read the Answer from at-2500 and the response from silajim
2. I followed the link in answer one -> [libxcb-xkb-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/trusty/libxcb-xkb-dev)
3. followed there the link for my architecture and memorized the files
4. I cd into my this directory and:  ls -l | grep xkb
5. turns out there are 2 missing *.so symlinks
6. Add missing symlinks:

   ```
    sudo ln -s libxkbfile.so.1.0.2 libxkbfile.so
    sudo ln -s libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0 libxkbcommon-x11.so
   ```
7. ran cmake in qtcreator
8. success